# How to perform exponential regression with more than one predictors using R

Tags: r, regression, nonlinear-regression

Fitting exponential regression of form $y=ab^{x_1}c^{x_2}$
Here $x_1$ and $x_2$ are predictors and $y$ is dependent variable
how to calculate $a,b,c$ using R tool

Comment: Are you expecting the errors to be additive ($y=ab^{x_1}c^{x_2}+\epsilon$) or multiplicative ($y=ab^{x_1}c^{x_2}\epsilon$)?

Answer (score 2):

If the model is:  log(y) ~ a + b*X1 + c*X2 with Poisson errors, .... then it would be as simple as:

```
glm( y ~ X1 + X2, data = dfrm, family="poisson")
```

You could get one kind of "additive" model with:

```
glm( log(y) ~ X1+X2, data=dfrm, family="gaussian")
```

Comment: Considering additive errors,Model that is to be fit is y=ay=ab^(x1)c^(x2) and if this equation is being log trransformed then for zeros in dataset R cannot generate equation as log(0) becomes infinity.

Comment: Then look at `?nls`.

Comment: you can use `glm(y ~X1+X2, data=dfrm, family=gaussian(link="log"))`; log-transformation is not involved ...

Comment: ... and the statistical model is actually `Y~Poisson(lambda=exp(a+b*log(X1)+c*log(X2)))` (equivalent to `lambda=exp(a)*X1^b*X2^c`), so that should be `glm(y~log(X1)+log(X2), ...)`