# How to perform an exponential regression with multiple variables in R

Tags: r, regression, multiple-regression, nonlinear-regression

I'd like to perform an exponential regression with multiple independent variables (similar to the LOGEST function in Excel)

I'm trying to model the function $Y = b {m_1}^{x_1}{m_2}^{x_2}$  where $b$ is a constant, $x_1$ and $x_2$ are my independent variables, and $m_1$ and $m_2$ are the coefficients of the independent variables.

I think I can linearize the function by doing something like `glm(log(Y) ~ x1 + x2)` but I don't totally understand why that would work. Also, I'd like to run a true non-linear regression if there is such a thing.

My goal is to run both a linear and an exponential regression, and find the best fit line based on the higher $R^2$ value.

I would also really appreciate your help in understanding how to plot the predicted curve in a scatter plot of my data as well.

Comment: the question of choosing `lm(log(Y) ~ x1 + x2)` versus the original exponential model is down to how you think the *error* behaves. If, in your data, you see that the noise increases as `x1` and `x2` increase, then you have good reason to use the log model, but if you see that it's constant, then the latter is more appropriate - my argument depends upon the lm function assuming constant variance of noise - i would have a look at http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/47063/how-to-perform-exponential-regression-with-more-than-one-predictors-using-r?rq=1

Comment: The correct `glm` formulation will work; it will perform well; and it will make other facilities available including hypothesis testing, prediction, and confidence intervals.  Use `glm(y ~ x1 + x2, gaussian(link="log")` .  If the software complains about being unable to finding a starting value for iteration, often just throwing a linear trend at it works, as in `glm(y ~ x1 + x2, gaussian(link="log"), mustart=1:length(y))` .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As a start:

```
f <- function(x1,x2,a,b1,b2) {a * (b1^x1) * (b2^x2) }

# generate some data
x1 <- 1:10
x2 <- c(2,3,5,4,6,7,8,10,9,11)
set.seed(44)
y <- 2*exp(x1/4) + rnorm(10)*2
dat <- data.frame(x1,x2, y)

# fit a nonlinear model
fm <- nls(y ~ f(x1,x2,a,b1,b2), data = dat, start = c(a=1, b1=1,b2=1))

# get estimates of a, b
co <- coef(fm)
```

Comment: Thank you! I've also posted the technique I used to plot a curve for this model below:

Answer (score 1):

Huub Hoofs' approach above worked! Thank you.  Here is the technique I utilized to plot a visualization of the model:

```
# x1 is the variable we want to show on the x-axis
plot(x1, y)

# generate a range of values for x1 in small increments to create a smooth line
xRange <- seq(min(x1), max(x1), length.out = 1000)

# generate the predicted y values (for a test value of x2 = 1)
yValues <- predict(fm, newdata=list(x1=xRange, x2=1))

#draw the curve
lines(xRange, yValues, col="blue")

# generate the predicted y values (for a test value of x2 = 0)
yValues <- predict(fm, newdata=list(x1=xRange, x2=0))

#draw the curve
lines(xRange, yValues, col="red")
```

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to look at R2, it's best to linearize your model.

Observe that R2 doesn't make sense for non linear general models, as discussed in another topic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14530770/calculating-r2-for-a-nonlinear-least-squares-fit

Note that the r squared is not defined for non-linear models, or at least very tricky, quote from R-help:

> There is a good reason that an nls model fit in R does not provide
> r-squared - r-squared doesn't make sense for a general nls model.
>
> One way of thinking of r-squared is as a comparison of the residual sum of squares for the fitted model to the residual sum of
> squares for a trivial model that consists of a constant only. You
> cannot guarantee that this is a comparison of nested models when
> dealing with an nls model. If the models aren't nested this comparison
> is not terribly meaningful.
>
> So the answer is that you probably don't want to do this in the first place.

If you want peer-reviewed evidence, see this article for example; it's not that you can't compute the R^2 value, it's just that it may not mean the same thing/have the same desirable properties as in the linear-model case.